# Chapman-Kolmogorov equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_n | n\ge 0\}$ be a Markov chain and
$p_{ij}(n) = P(X_n = j | X_0 = i)$.

For $1\le m<n$ we get:

$$p_{ij}(n) = \sum_{k\in S} P(X_n=j|X_m = k, X_0 = i)P(X_m=k| X_0=i) = \sum_{k\in S} p_{kj}(n-m)p_{ik}(m)$$.

My question is trivial - why $P(X_n=j|X_m = k, X_0 = i)= p_{kj}(n-m)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X_n = j \mid X_m = k, X_0 = i) = P(X_n = j \mid X_m = k) = P(X_{n-m} = j \mid X_0 = k) =: p_{kj}(n-m).$$

The first equality is due to the Markov property. The second equality is due to time-homogeneity of the Markov process.

Comment: I can't see where we use the Markov property in the first equality.

Comment: @MadChemist : Perhaps you can describe the meaning of "Markov property" as you see it.

Comment: @Michael I mean $$P(X_n = k_n | X_{n-1} = k_{n-1},..., X_0 = k_0) = P(X_n = k_n | X_{n-1} = k_{n-1})$$

Comment: There are two issues here, one is removing conditions about the irrelevant past, the other is recursively extending the Markov property to the future.  For the first, If $A, B$ are events and $Z$ a random vector that takes values in a finite or countably infinite set  $\mathcal{Z}$ then 

$$P[A|B] = \sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}} P[A|B,Z=z]P[Z=z|B]$$ So you can define  $A=\{X_n=k\}$, $B=\{X_{n-1}=k_{n-1}, X_0=k_0\}$, $Z=(X_{n-2}, …, X_1)$ to get \begin{align}&P[X_n=k|X_{n-1}=k_{n-1}, X_0=k_0]\\&= \sum_{z} P[X_n=k|X_{n-1}=k_{n-1},X_{n-2}=z_{n-2}, ..., X_1=z_1,X_0=k_0]P[Z=z|B]\\&=...\end{align}

Comment: A way to remember the Markov property is _The future states are conditionally independent of the past, given the current state_.